# How to set a session variable when clicking a <a> link

Tags: php, html, ajax, session

I have the following problem... I want to set a session variable when clicking on a normal link like:

```
<a href="home" name="home">home</a>
```

My research seems to point out that it is not possible for PHP to catch up with the click event in a such a way that it would set a session variable.

I believe it is possible with Ajax, but how? And what would my link look like?
Setting the session variable should look like:

```
$_SESSION['link'] = home;
```

So in short: When clicking on a link in HTML, a session variable must be set.
HOW am i going to do that?

PS: I'm not quite familiar with Ajax, but I'll catch up.

EDIT: The links will refer to the same page, also i want to avoid urls like "home.php?link=X".
If it isn't possible to do it any other way, too bad. But I'll hope there is a solution.
**Important:** the name of the link will be the value of `$_SESSION['link']`

Comment: So I'm confused, what happens after you click the link? Does it generate the session, then return the session id and use it in the link, or just making a call before it runs the link? This seems like you're brute-forcing catching a session-timeout and using a redirect to login?

Comment: Here's the scenario: I'm on home.php, I'll click on a link which goes to home.php. I want to catch the click event and make the name of my link the value of my session variable. But since the link is in HTML it is client sided and not server sided.

Comment: HTML will make the page reload, doesn't it? So than you can catch it with PHP the way @Brandon is describing it.

Comment: what's wrong with urls like "home.php?link=X"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['current'])){
         $_SESSION['oldlink']=$_SESSION['current'];
    }else{
         $_SESSION['oldlink']='no previous page';
    }
    $_SESSION['current']=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Maybe this is what you're looking for?
It will remember the old link/page you're coming from (within your website).

Put that piece on top of each page.

If you want to make it 'refresh proof' you can add another check:

```
   if(isset($_SESSION['current']) && $_SESSION['current']!=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

This will make the page not remember itself.

**UPDATE:** Almost the same as @Brandon though...
Just use a php variable, I know this looks like a security risk, but when done correct it isn't.

```
 <a href="home.php?a=register">Register Now!</a>
```

PHP:

```
 if(isset($_GET['a']) /*you can validate the link here*/){
    $_SESSION['link']=$_GET['a'];
 }
```

Why even store the GET in a session? Just use it.
Please tell me why you do not want to use GET. « Validate for more security.
I maybe can help you with a better script.

Comment: The problem is, the links will refer to the page they are in. So $_SESSION['current'] will always be home.php. I need the name of the link to make that my session variable.
Thanks for the code though :).

Comment: I need some content to be called from the database depending on the variable, and with that also the name of the link. Because of the page refresh, when clicking on a link, the variable must be a $_SESSION var.

Comment: I want to avoid GET because I don't want to mess up my url and because of some security issues. Maybe I can unset the GET after using it and then refresh the page again... Also I thought this would be possible with Ajax, but I haven't heard that in the answers so far...

Comment: Isn't that a bit too direct Col.? Bit offensive?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - Again, I believe it is possible with Ajax. Moreover I don't like your comment... Read my whole question please "If it isn't possible to do it any other way, too bad." Which implies I'm forced to use GET... There is no need to vote down this legitimate question, and the answer of @Superspy.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I do not htink he does :S 'He count himself as a seasoned programmer' Instead he is friendly and tries to find a solution for his problem, so be it that he does not want to use GET.

Comment: @Superspy - Thanks for all the help! I'll give you the credit. I'll probably use your first piece of code, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem - i wanted to pass a parameter to another page by clicking a hyperlink and get the value to go to the next page (without using GET because the parameter is stored in the URL).

to those who don't understand why you would want to do this the answer is you dont want the user to see sensitive information or you dont want someone editing the GET.

well after scouring the internet it seemed it wasnt possible to make a normal hyperlink using the POST method.

And then i had a eureka moment!!!!
why not just use CSS to make the submit button look like a normal hyperlink??? ...and put the value i want to pass in a hidden field

i tried it and it works. you can see an exaple here http://paulyouthed.com/test/css-button-that-looks-like-hyperlink.php

the basic code for the form is:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="page-to-pass-to.php" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post-variable-name" value="value-you-want-pass"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="whatever" value="text-to-display" id="hyperlink-style-button"/>
                </form>
```

the basic css is:

```
    #hyperlink-style-button{
      background:none;
      border:0;
      color:#666;
      text-decoration:underline;
    }

    #hyperlink-style-button:hover{
      background:none;
      border:0;
      color:#666;
      text-decoration:none;
      cursor:pointer;
      cursor:hand;
    }
```

Comment: Don't you want one of those CSS declarations to be `#hyperlink-style-button:hover { ... }`?

Comment: THANK YOU!! This was just what I needed. Using JS and ajax was just really messy and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

In HTML:

```
<a href="index.php?link=home" name="home">home</a>
```

Then in PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['link'])){$_SESSION['link'] = $_GET['link'];}
```

Comment: I won't down-vote this one, but I will say I don't recommend it. While it works in innocuous code, anything that touches a database needs to be properly escaped, as the client can send whatever they want through, using this method.

Answer (score 2):

Is your link to another web page? If so, perhaps you could put the variable in the query string and set the session variable when the page being linked to is loaded.

So the link looks like this:

```
<a href="home.php?variable=value" name="home">home</a>
```

And the homge page would parse the query string and set the session variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does refer to the same page. I will make my post more clear.