# Check refering link with php session

Tags: php, session, hyperlink

I was trying to use the solution posted on [How to set a session variable when clicking a <a> link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854754/how-to-set-a-session-variable-when-clicking-a-a-link)

but I can't get it to work, to only allow access from a specific URL. As example I only want users to access the php page with a link on http://www.examplesite.com en disable direct access to page.php.
I used http_referer, which is working in Firefox, but in IE it isn't working.

I use the link:

```
<a href="page.php?a=validate">
```

and on the php page I use the following code:

```
session_start();
 if(isset($_GET['a']) /*you can validate the link here*/){
    $_SESSION['link']=$_GET['a'];
 }else{
         $_SESSION['oldlink']='no previous page';
 }
 $_SESSION['current']=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

I'm not a star with php and probably missing something.
Could someone help me with this?